# How does this Anamorphic illusion work?

Tags: optics

I just saw this illusion

https://www.instagram.com/p/BWiom73l5tk/?hl=en

The characters are visible only when viewed through an angle.

How does this actually work and what steps goes in to making it?

I could not find any reference to this particular illusion. I know anamorphic, but I found that it has many varieties The problem is there is no particular term for this kind of anamorphic illusion, so how do I search it ? That is the main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the card closely. Look at the size / area of the rectangular blocks of print compared to the narrow straight lines. Then think what happens when you tilt the card, foreshortening occurs and the blocks get emphasized and more prominent.

It's made by clever printing.

[Foreshortening Anamorphic](https://anamorphicart.wordpress.com) and scroll down half the page. It says tilting produces the effect

Comment: thanks for your answer. the link looks very informative. will read it and then will put my comments.

Comment: No problem, see can you do the same trick with your comments:)

Comment: It worked :-)  Basically  I just drew elongated characters in narrow strips and that's all :-)

Comment: Great  to hear that. It comes back to biology and our relatively good eyesight, making up for  our lack of smell, compared to other animals. I do know that our brains process colors and symmetry faster than other visual cues, as our ancestors had to spot, say a lion looking at them through high  grass, pretty sharpish. And also the colors chosen for direction and exit signs when driving.